# app size is increased due to cnic scanner

Tags: flutter, dart

When i use google_ml_kit package to scan id card to extract text the apk size increase to 138 mb which is too much please guide me use alternative package or how to reduce file size

I have used cnic_scanner to scan id card but now used google_ml_kit but size remain constant

Comment: thanx in advance to pay head my question

Comment: You can use Flutter Devtools to find out which packages take more size https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/app-size

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.